# Are there any civilian powered-lift aircraft besides the AW609?

Tags: powered-lift

I was looking at the difference between rotorcraft and powered-lift and every example I saw was a military application (Osprey or Harrier or F35)

The FAA defines powered-lift:

> Powered-lift means a heavier-than-air aircraft capable of vertical
>   takeoff, vertical landing, and low speed flight that depends
>   principally on engine-driven lift devices or engine thrust for lift
>   during these flight regimes and on nonrotating airfoil(s) for lift
>   during horizontal flight.

I was wondering if there were any small, personal powered-lift aircraft that one might get their private pilot license in the way people get a ASEL certificate in a 172.

I know there is the [AW609](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AgustaWestland_AW609), but that is targeted towards the business market with a very specific niche.

Comment: The Harrier has some private owners and could be considered a "small" powered lift aircraft. The issue I see though is that powered lift is somewhere between a helicopter and an airplane, and is probably not the best choice of aircraft for primary training.

Answer (score 3):

I suppose some kinds of roadable aircraft aka 'flying car' designs would qualify under the powered lift category.  One example which nearly escaped the prototype stage was the Moeller SkyCar.

[image]

But beyond the Agusta AW609, I cannot think of any other powered lift category aircraft which are, or may be soon, available for sale to the general public.

Comment: The first Powered Lift pilot certificates were awarded to [V-22 Osprey test pilots in 1997](http://boeing.mediaroom.com/1997-08-21-Osprey-Pilots-Receive-First-FAA-Powered-Lift-Ratings), I'm not sure if the certificate applies to experimental category aircraft though. The only reference I can find about it in the FAR's [(61.163)](http://www.ecfr.gov/cgi-bin/text-idx?c=ecfr;sid=65e0268f6c19eafdc3a54610140a0030;rgn=div6;view=text;node=14:2.0.1.1.2.7;idno=14;cc=ecfr) applies to ATP and commercial certificates.

Comment: Interesting. I think the V-22 Osprey is such a neat design, it makes sense that it required a whole new class of certificates.

Comment: Looks like the Terrafugia TF-X (looks like it's currently in dream phase) might be in this class. (https://www.terrafugia.com/tf-x/)

Comment: Moller is still around and still working on prototypes, though whether they can bring something to market is questionable.